# About Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Kaali Maa

Tags: durga, kali, ramakrishna

Did anywhere history record that, Kaali maa appeared in front of Ramakrishna Paramahamsa?
Whats the significance of the picture,image we see  in net, where Kaali Maa appeared before Paramahamsa.
is it just a caricature created  by Ramakrishna math ? or whats the story behind this.

[image]

also, whats the symbolism behind this image, why Paramahamsa chosen KAli ma as HIS IshtaDevata

link to pic : https://www.facebook.com/AadiParashakti/photos/ramakrishna-wouldnt-eat-unless-mother-kali-eats-first-this-used-to-be-a-daily-af/2206381772796451/

Comment: Some of his visions are told in his disciple Swami Saradananda's book "Sri Ramakrishna- The Great Master" and in Swami Nikhilananda's "The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna" - both available online here - https://ramakrishnavivekananda.info/

Answer (score 3):

In His Gospel , Ramakrishna Paramahamsa described many times the Divine Mother as Kali. Quoting from the Gospel :

> "Why is Krishna tribhanga, bent in three places? Because of His love for Radha. That which is Brahman is also Kali, the Adyasakti, who creates, preserves, and destroys the universe. He who is Krishna is the same as Kali. The root is one-all these are His sport and play.

> O mind, you do not know how to farm! Fallow lies the field of your life.If you had only worked it well, How rich a harvest you might reap! Hedge it about with Kali's name If you would keep your harvest safe; This is the stoutest hedge of all, For Death himself cannot come near it.

> As is a man's meditation, so is his feeling of love; As is a man's feeling of love, so is his gain; And faith is the root of all.If in the Nectar Lake of Mother Kali's feet My mind remains immersed, Of little use are worship, oblations, or sacrifice.
> Why should I go to Ganga or Gaya, to Kasi, Kanchi, or Prabhas, So long as I can breathe my last with Kali's name upon my lips?..

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Kali appeared to ramakrishna in many visions,according to ramakrisna himself.this started when he was about to kill himself,but kali emanated a divine light from her murti anbd he  realized the state of parabhairava(nomndual reality).

Comment: Was the Bhava of Kali Maa ,something similar as a Roudra Moorthy ? Or appeared in front of Him as beloved Mother ? Whether paramahamsa installed deitys in any part of bengal ? If yes ,whose ?

Comment: @DasAD,kali appeared to him as kali.he also had visions of all the mahavidyas.his wife was kali maa and turned into kali when some robbers were trying to rob her.those robbers converted to the kaula path.